# How to save django fields using objects.create?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a model :

```
class Certificate(models.Model):
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    generic_certificate = models.ForeignKey(GenericCertificate, related_name='certificates_awarded')
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag', related_name='certificates_awarded', null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    history_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    rewardee = models.ForeignKey(OrganisationUser, related_name='certificates_rewarded')
    position =  models.CharField(max_length=50, default = '0,0')
```

I want to save position fields given primary-key.

Here is views.py :

```
def post(self, request , *args , **kwargs): 
        comments = Certificate.objects.values("comments").filter(pk = kwargs.get('cert_id') )
        gen_certi = Certificate.objects.values("generic_certificate").filter(pk = kwargs.get('cert_id') ) 
        tag = Certificate.objects.values("tag").filter(pk = kwargs.get('cert_id') )
        history_timestamp = Certificate.objects.values("history_timestamp").filter(pk = kwargs.get('cert_id') )
        rewardee = Certificate.objects.values("rewardee").filter(pk = kwargs.get('cert_id') )
        position = request.POST.get('hid')
        position = str([position])
        a = Certificate.objects.create( comments=comments, generic_certificate = gen_certi , tag=tag,rewardee=rewardee, position=position )
        print a
```

Its giving error :

```
Exception Value:    
Cannot assign "[{'generic_certificate': 2}]": "Certificate.generic_certificate" must be a "GenericCertificate" instance.
```

Please help how to save   position field into database.

Comment: you want to update the same record or want to add new record in database for the `position` you read from `request.POST`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gen_certi` variable is a queryset (list of objects), because you are using `filter()` - use `get()` instead:

```
gen_certi = Certificate.objects.get(pk = kwargs.get('cert_id')).generic_certificate
```

Actually, I don't understand what are you planning to do in the view. If you are modifying the object, there is no need to overwrite the existing fields, just update the fields that are passed to the view in `request.POST`, like position:

```
try:
    certificate = Certificate.objects.get(pk = kwargs.get('cert_id'))
    certificate.position = request.POST.get('hid')
    certificate.save()
except DoesNotExist: 
    # create new certificate
    certificate = Certificate()
    ...
```

Hope that helps.